# Specifying DateTime.ToString("o") decimal precision

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I have a DateTime object which I'm trying to output into an xml file in an ISO 8601 compliant format for transmission between two systems - we have no control over the recipient. The .net [round trip format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) satisfies this requirement for the most part, however forces the precision to 7dp.

Is there a way I can specify this? eg something like `"o:0"` to omit the milliseconds decimal places completely or `"o:3"` to set it to 3dp instead. I know I can format the output myself with `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK` (or `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffK` respectively) as a custom format specifier to control the decimal places if necessary, but wanted to see if I missed a way to simply pass the decimal precision to the `"o"` format specifier.

Comment: If the documentation is anything to go by, i dont think so

Comment: Sadly that's what I'm suspecting. I'm going to have a dig through the corefx source on github and see if there's anything there that's undocumented. Just thought I'd ask here in case anyone had dealt with this before. I'll be sure to update/answer if I find anything in case anyone else needs this in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the answer to this is no, there's nothing (in the core framework at least) to customize this. Looking at the [source code for `DateTime` roundtrip formatting](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c6018efcaff74a2068772d7fbc275ad57577bae6/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Globalization/DateTimeFormat.cs#L1108) this is hardcoded to 7dp:

```
// Omitted for brevity
...
AppendHHmmssTimeOfDay(result, dateTime);
result.Append('.');

long fraction = dateTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
AppendNumber(result, fraction, 7);
```

If anybody is interested, my solution was to implement a custom `ToFormattedString()` extenstion method to handle this which will replace the format string with a custom one if necessary and call `ToString` with that:

```
using System.Globalization; // System.Globalization needed for IFormatProvider overload
using System.Text; // System.Text required for StringBuilder class

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class DateTimeFormatExtension
    {
        // Consts for building the custom format string
        private const string ROUNDTRIP_FORMAT_PREFIX = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss";
        private const char ROUNDTRIP_FORMAT_FRACTION = 'f';
        private const char ROUNDTRIP_FORMAT_SUFFIX = 'K';

        // Appending the 'f' custom format string maxes out at "fffffff"(7 dp) and will throw an exception if given more 
        private const int DATETIME_MAX_DP = 7;

        private static int GetRoundtripLength(int decimalPlaces) =>
            ROUNDTRIP_FORMAT_PREFIX.Length + decimalPlaces + 2; // +2 to account for the '.' and the 'K' suffix

        public static string ToFormattedString(this DateTime input) => input.ToString();

        public static string ToFormattedString(this DateTime input, string format)
        {
            var provider = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
            return input.ToFormattedString(format, provider);
        }

                    public static string ToFormattedString(this DateTime input, string format, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            string parsedFormat = format;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(format))
            {
                switch (format[0])
                {
                    case 'o':
                    case 'O':
                        var precision = format.Substring(1);
                        // Only do this if we have a custom 'o' string, otherwise us the base functionality
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(precision))
                        {
                            // If the custom addition to the format string is an integer, use that to determine dp
                            if (int.TryParse(precision, out int decimalCount))
                            {
                                // Build the format string
                                var formatBuilder = new StringBuilder(GetRoundtripLength(decimalCount));
                                formatBuilder.Append(ROUNDTRIP_FORMAT_PREFIX);

                                // Append '.' and 'f' chars to format string (Append nothing if 0 dp)
                                if (decimalCount > 0)
                                {
                                    formatBuilder
                                        .Append('.')
                                        .Append(ROUNDTRIP_FORMAT_FRACTION,
                                            // Cap max dp length to avoid exceptions
                                            Math.Min(decimalCount, DATETIME_MAX_DP));
                                }

                                // Append 'K' suffix
                                formatBuilder.Append(ROUNDTRIP_FORMAT_SUFFIX);
                                parsedFormat = formatBuilder.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return input.ToString(parsedFormat, provider);
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
using Extensions;
...
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
string result;
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString(); // empty just calls the default ToString()
// result: "2018-03-02 12:31:17 AM"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("dd/MM/yy ssmmhh"); // custom format strings still work
// result: "02-03-18 173112"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("d"); // standard format strings still work
// result: "2018-03-02"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("D");
// result: "Friday, March 2, 2018"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("F");
// result: "Friday, March 2, 2018 12:31:17 AM"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("o"); // standard format specifier uses default ToString("o") behaviour
// result: "2018-03-02T00:31:17.9818727Z"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("o0"); // no decimal places
// result: "2018-03-02T00:31:17Z"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("o3"); // 3 decimal places
// result: "2018-03-02T00:31:17.981Z"
result = currentDateTime.ToFormattedString("o100"); // too many decimals cap at 7
// result: "2018-03-02T00:31:17.9818727Z"
```

EDIT: Updated to remove the ":" from format string to keep in line with the way decimal precision is specified on [numeric formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings):

> A standard numeric format string takes the form `Axx`, where:
>
> `A` is a single alphabetic character called the format specifier.
>
> `...`
>
> `xx` is an optional integer called the precision specifier

Comment: Although I like your customized format, for many would having the full custom format string be ok too.

It is: "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"
and would result in
"2021-06-10T20:05:00"
var myDt = DateTime.UtcNow;
var myFmt = myDt.ToString(""yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"")